# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.oreilly.servlet.MultipartRequest

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, file-upload

i am trying to upload an text file on apache tomcat 6 server.
i am using cos.jar for uploading this file.But i am getting this problem.

root cause

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/oreilly/servlet/MultipartRequest
xlValidatorServlet.doPost(xlValidatorServlet.java:37)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:643)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:723)

**My console is**

Feb 07, 2015 3:48:45 PM   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve        invoke
```

SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet xlValidatorServlet threw exception
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.oreilly.servlet.MultipartRequest
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1680)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1526)
    at xlValidatorServlet.doPost(xlValidatorServlet.java:37)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:643)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:723)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:861)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:620)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Answer (score 1):

This is caused by your classpath missing the library (jar) having the class "com.oreilly.servlet.MultipartRequest", or missing the class in your version of cos.jar.

In Tomcat there are couple of ways to add the required libraries to the classpath. However in your case you can add the library to the classpath by putting it inside the following location "`/yourapp/WEB-INF/lib/cos.jar`"

If you have already added this to the classpath, then check to see if the class "com.oreilly.servlet.MultipartRequest" is available in your cos.jar.(Sometimes different versions of libraries have different classes or they might be missing).